# problem with jquery .load() with dynamic js

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load

I have a problem with .load() of jquery, 
I need to load in a div a page that loads its data dynamically through javascript, in particular I have my html page which through a js in a function uses the .load of jquery:

```
myClickAnimElement("#ese_div_book", function() {
    if (_lese_Stop) { return; }
    myStopAudio();
    $('#contenitore_libro').load('../librohtml/containerLibro.php?lis=AB #containerlibro');


});
```

what loads me into the DIV are only the html elements, but what I need is that it also loads the js that dynamically arrive at the containerlibro.php page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">


<head>



    <!--META-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!--Link-->


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../librohtml/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/assets/css/nav_bar.css">


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../librohtml/AB/css/menuAB.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/AB/css/libroAB.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/assets/css/navAB.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/assets/images/nextAB.svg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../librohtml/assets/images/prevAB.svg">

</head>


<body>
    <!--<div class="scrollbox">-->
    <div id="containerlibro">
        <div class="barra_enter">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <div class="link-list-wrapper">
                        <li>
                            <a class="list-item" href="#">
                                <p class="pubblicazione"></p>
                                <div class="prev" onClick="indietro()"><img class="prev-img" src=""> </div>
                                <div class="bottone">
                                    <button class="indice" id="idx_button2"><span>Indice</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="next" onClick="avanti()"><img class="next-img" src=""> </div>
                                <input type="text" name="testo" class="scrivi_cerca" id="search-in" onClick="tastiera()" placeholder="cerca nel libro…">
                                <button class="btn-search" id="myButton" value="Highlight multiple search terms" onClick="ricerca();"><img class="img_search" alt="foto" src="assets/images/lente2.svg"></button>
                                <div class="box" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                    <button class="next-search" onClick="nextsearch()">Next-search</button>
                                    <div class="text-area" id="text_search"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="exit" onClick="chiudi()">X</button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="marginSX" class="margin"></div>


        <div id="genera" class="hyphenate scrollbox-content" lang="it"></div>
        <div id="marginDX" class="margin"></div>
        <!-- <div class="scrollbar_y"></div>-->
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

in my static page the content of the #genera div is processed through an engineV7 file that loads a whole file called sectionsAB in which there is the real book, instead with the .load () only the static divs are loaded but not the book structured, how do you dynamically load files using jquery .load () or similar?

Comment: what HTML element is `#contenitore_libro`? an `iframe`?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply! Before is a normal div, after, i try with iframe but i have a problem to load on Mobile Device, on desktop now load of page is ok but not start in mobDevice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now the problem is resolved in mobile smartphone, bt not in apple device!

```
<body>
    <div id="ese_div_book" class="ese_button ese_quiz ese_colorBT2">
        <img id="ese_book" class="myButton" src="assets/img/Bt_Book.svg">
    </div>
    <div id="contenitore_libro" style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height:100%;top: 0%;left: 0%;z-index: 999999999;visibility: hidden;">
        <iframe id="frame" src="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
        </iframe>
        <button id="button_book" class="ese_button ese_quiz ese_colorBT1 ese_norm" style="visibility: hidden;position: fixed;top: 95%;width: 5%;height: 5%;left: 95%;background-color: lightskyblue;">
            <img id="ese_back" class="myButton" src="assets/img/menu/IndietroW.svg">
        </button>

    </div>

</body>

<script>
    $("#ese_div_book").click(function() {
        $("#contenitore_libro").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#button_book").css("visibility", "visible");
        // console.log("ARRIVA VALORE", _nQuest);
        $("#frame").attr("src", "../librohtml/index.html?id=" + _nQuest.Libro3 + "&tit=yes&lis=AB");

    });
    $("#button_book").click(function() {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#contenitore_libro").css("visibility", "hidden");
        return false
    })
</script>
```

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply! Before is a normal div, after, i try with iframe but i have a problem to load on Mobile Device, on desktop now load of page is ok but not start in mobDevice!

```
  <div id="contenitore_libro" style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height:100%;top: 0%;left: 0%;z-index: 999999999;visibility: hidden;">
        <iframe id="frame" src="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
        </iframe>
        <button id="button_book" class="ese_button ese_quiz ese_colorBT1 ese_norm" style="visibility: hidden;position: fixed;top: 95%;width: 5%;height: 5%;left: 95%;background-color: lightskyblue;">
            <img id="ese_back" class="myButton" src="assets/img/menu/IndietroW.svg">
        </button>

    </div>




$("#ese_div_book").click(function() {
        $("#contenitore_libro").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#button_book").css("visibility", "visible");
        console.log("ARRIVA VALORE", _nQuest);
        $("#frame").attr("src", "http://localhost/librohtml/index.html?id=" + _nQuest.Libro3 + "&tit=yes&lis=AB");

    });
    $("#button_book").click(function() {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#contenitore_libro").css("visibility", "hidden");
        return false
    })
```

Comment: now the problem is resolved in mobile smartphone, bt not in apple device!